# How do I set my Logitech harmony remote to control my Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, remote-control

I know I can teach the Apple TV to "learn" a 3rd party remote, but thats not what I'm looking for.

I want to add the Apple TV as a device, and I know it's possible, but I don't know where to find the right device in the harmony menus.   I know it's possible, as i know others who have done it in the past, but am no longer in touch with them.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the correct setting is found in the following location

```
Computer-> Media Center PC -> Apple -> Apple TV
```

Answer (score 0):

Type in the model number as well
example: Apple/TV3

Comment: This worked for me!